# Database model for car-service

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a project for car-service(denting, painting). In this app user will select their location and then select car brand,model and fuel type.After this he will see a list of services and add them to cart . Then he can make order for services.
So, How to design database for this.I am stuck with how store services which can be  change in price for different car and location.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to break it down into smaller ones.

Comment: @The impaler, My main problem is to store services like Glass repair, Denting ,painting for different car  and different location.Because services have different prices for different cars. So how to design table for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a table like this one can help you model the price changes:

```
create table service (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50)
);

create table car_type (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50)
);

create table location (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50)
);

create table service_price (
  service_id int not null,
  car_type_id int not null,
  location_id int not null,
  price numeric(12,2) not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key service_id references service (id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key car_type_id references car_type (id),
  constraint fk3 foreign key location_id references location (id)
);
```

This way the price is stored separately per service, per car type, and per location.